# Two Controller Action(sharing same model) use same View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I had two controller action both both sharing same model. Can I return them in same View?

Reason beingI need to show 2 category in one view. One category to show all users IN role and another category to show users NOT IN role.

Wondering how can I do this? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely. You can have the same model and view for different actions in a controller. Here I show you how to have 1 View for *Create* and *Edit* actions.

1 **Model** for both actions:

```
public class CreateEditModel
{
    public CreateEditViewMode Mode { get; set; }
    public string AnOtherProperty { get; set; }
}

public enum CreateEditViewMode { Create, Edit }
```

Property `Mode` of `CreateEditModel` will help us to customize the view for each action.

**Actions:**

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Models.CreateEditModel model = new Models.CreateEditModel();
        model.Mode = Models.CreateEditViewMode.Create;
        //Manipulate model
        return View("CreateEdit", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Models.CreateEditModel model = new Models.CreateEditModel();
        model.Mode = Models.CreateEditViewMode.Edit;
        //Manipulate model
        return View("CreateEdit", model);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        // TODO: Add update logic here
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Notice how we assign `model.Mode` in `[HttpGet]` actions so:
 1. We can customize view.
 2. View can be posted back to the proper `[HttpPost]` action.

1 **view** for both actions:

```
@using MvcApplication1.Models
@model MvcApplication1.Models.CreateEditModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Model.Mode.ToString();
}

<h2>@Model.Mode.ToString()</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm(Model.Mode.ToString(), "Home"))
{
   <input type="submit"
          value="@(Model.Mode == CreateEditViewMode.Create ? "Create" : "Update")" />
}
```

The tricky part is using the following [overload of `FormExtensions.BeginForm()` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492590.aspx):

```
  public static MvcForm BeginForm(
      this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
      string actionName,
      string controllerName
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want one view to display two different lists of users: a list of users in the given role, and another list of users not in the given role.

This is entirely possible - using the concept of `ViewModel`.  You create a class with all the different properties your view will require, and use this as the model for your view.  Modify your controller action to set all the necessary propeties

e.g.

The ViewModel

```
public class UserListViewModel
{
   public string Role { get; set; }
   public List<User> UsersInRole { get; set; }
   public List<User> UsersNotInRole  { get; set; }
}
```

The controller action

```
public ActionResult ShowRoleDetails ( string role ) {

    var model = new UserListViewModel();

    model.Role = role;
    model.UsersInRole = //some code to get users in the given role
    model.UsersNotInRole  = //some code to get users not in the given role

    return View(model);
}
```

The View

```
@model ViewModel
...

<h1>Users in @Model.Role</h1>
@foreach (var user in Model.UsersInRole)
{
   <p>@user.Name
}

<h1>Users not in @Model.Role</h1>
@foreach (var user in Model.UsersNotInRole)
{
   <p>@user.Name
}
```